# Why is Swiper automatically setting width on swiper-slide?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-component, swiper.js

I have the following markup and script setup for swiper:

```html
<div class="swiper">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
import Swiper, { Navigation, Pagination } from 'swiper';
import 'swiper/css';
import 'swiper/css/navigation';
import 'swiper/css/pagination';

const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
  modules: [Navigation, Pagination],
});
```

It is a very basic setup however I'm not sure why the width property gets automatically set to the .swiper-slide element.
I would like to customize so that .swiper-slide element has width to whatever the content is inside of it.

Comment: Are you looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68908072/swiper-js-slide-width ...?

Comment: Define the width by yourself. I feel like using slidePerView: auto, or have you considered other libraries?