# Swiper do not set slides width to "auto"

Tags: javascript, html, css, width, swiper.js

I am trying to make width of my slides in future - by their width. I have already tried thousand of recommendations but nothing helped me. Can you recommend something to me, so that my slides will appear by their width (at 1 page)?

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="/style1.5test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@11/swiper-bundle.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="swiper">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide card"><span>Four words text</span></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide card"><span>Two words</span></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide card"><span>Just three words</span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@11/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/script-test.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}

.swiper-slide {
    width: auto;
}

.swiper-slide span {
    background: yellow;
}
```

JS

```
const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
    slidesPerView: 'auto',
    spaceBetween: 10
});
```

I am trying to achieve width of my slides by their content

Comment: I tested your code and it works. [codepen](https://codepen.io/imhvost/pen/OJdWOpM) When you don't provide a minimal reproducible example of your problem where everyone can see exactly the problem - it's wasting your time and mine!

Comment: Thats because you launched Codepen without "normal" initialising via <link> and <script> attributes. I have tried copypaste my code, which do not work in my VS Code to your Code Pen and it didn't work; Only when i have deleted all external links it began to work; Try to copypaste my code to your VS Code/Web Storm and you will see this problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swiper.js slide width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68908072/swiper-js-slide-width)

Comment: Unfortunately, no

Comment: You need to include your styles AFTER the swiper styles.
Or set `.swiper-slide { width: auto !important; }`

Comment: Including styles to my class "card" instead of "swiper-slide" didn't help, of course if this AFTER you meant. Adding "!important" helped, but this way will close for me media requests in CSS in the future, because swiper do not react without "!important", not only to "width" (to "overflow" and other things too). The main painfull thing that in all videos in youtube everything worked for other people. That's what i don't like=((

Answer (score 0):

So you want each slide to be as wide as its content? It seems `width: fit-content` is the key.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

swiper-slide {
  padding: 1em;
  height: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@11/swiper-element-bundle.min.js"></script>

<swiper-container slides-per-view="auto">
  <swiper-slide style="background: yellow;">Four words text</swiper-slide>
  <swiper-slide style="background: lightblue;">Two words</swiper-slide>
  <swiper-slide style="background: red;">Just three words</swiper-slide>
  <swiper-slide style="background: pink;">This one is a bit longer than the others</swiper-slide>
  <swiper-slide style="background: green;">The fifth one</swiper-slide>
  <swiper-slide style="background: violet;">The sixth one</swiper-slide>
  <swiper-slide style="background: orange;">The seventh one</swiper-slide>
  <swiper-slide style="background: tan;">The eighth one</swiper-slide>
</swiper-container>
```

Comment: Brett Donald, try to put your "swiper-slide" tags in more realistic situation. For example in divs with class="swiper-slide". And you will see. And now according to Swiper documentation swiper container was removed and now it has "swiper" --> "swiper-wrapper" --> "swiper-slide" building